# Change Container Assigned IP address

Tags: mysql, docker

I want to create a container with its own static IP address.

I am using this command:

```
$sudo docker run -d -p 172.17.0.55::3306 mysql
```

And the result is:

```
e7e8d812163bfcc333f24bdad23b67382fdb5b9ca57e75cb65d8ed0feb4e2dc3

Error response from daemon: Cannot start container
e7e8d812163bfcc333f24bdad23b67382fdb5b9ca57e75cb65d8ed0feb4e2dc3: 
Error starting

userland proxy: listen tcp 172.17.0.55:32827: bind: cannot assign requested address
```

where it went wrong??

Answer (score 0):

To give static ip to you containers you can use either weave or rancher. If you love to work from command line i suggest using weave.

Weave creates its own network and assigns static ips to containers. Also weave is lightweight with just 10 mb container. So you can assign ips like 10.42.0.1 etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But my problem is this is a docker supported command and it didn't work with my. But I'll try weave for sure.

Comment: Hope @walid you could have tried with weave and should solved your problem.